# Android circular crop image using com.android.camera.action.CROP returning black image in HTC devices

Tags: android, crop, android-camera-intent

In my application user can select image from camera or gallery in android. After selecting image, user can also crop circular image from that original image. But after circle cropping, I am getting black rectangle image from that in HTC devices(explorer and other HTC devices). In samsung devices it works fine. I am using below code to crop image:

```
intent.setDataAndType(selectedImage, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
intent.putExtra("circleCrop", "true");
startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
```

Here is my onactivityresult method where i will get cropped image:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap photo = null;

    if (extras != null) {
    photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
    }
    if (photo != null) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
    byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
    FileOutputStream out;// = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    out = openFileOutput("cropImage.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    out.write(b);
    out.close();
     pref.edit().putString(PrefernceData.PREF_IMAGE_CROP_URL,"cropImage.png").commit();
    Log.i("capute", "success after crop......");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

In above code, when I just remove this line :intent.putExtra("circleCrop", "true"); It works fine for rectangle crop image on all HTC as well as samsung devices. But i want circle crop image only. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Besides putting only image name into the Shareprefrences try to put the whole path of the image where your cropped image has been stored.

Comment: Problem is not about image path, I am getting bitmap(in my case photo) itself as black image.of 96 x 96.

Answer (score 0):

The intent you're using isn't actually an official part of Dalvik. It works on many devices but there is no guarantee it will work the same on any/all of them. You can see some alternate libraries you may use in [this blog](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/205).

Some newer alternatives can be found [here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) .